# How to compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 2^n + 3^n +4^n+5^n)^{1/n}$?

Tags: calculus

How to compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 2^n + 3^n +4^n+5^n)^{1/n}$?

My partial solution: $(1 + 2^n + 3^n +4^n+5^n)^{1/n} \leq (5 \times 5^n)^{1/n}$. Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 2^n + 3^n +4^n+5^n)^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} 5^{(n+1)/n} = 5$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For the other direction, estimate below by $5=(5^n)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $$5^n\le 1+2^n+3^n+4^n+5^n$$