# convergence of $(2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Prove that the sequence $\{(2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\}$ converges and find its limit.

I've deduced that the sequence will converge to $3$, just need help writing a formal proof of this fact.

Comment: Rewrite it as $3 \times \left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$ which is more than $3$ and less than or equal to $ 3 +3\times \left(\frac23\right)^n$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079634/how-to-compute-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-1-2n-3n-4n5n1-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out $3$ from the expression:
$$ (2^n+3^n)^{\frac1n}=3\biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac23\Bigr)^n\biggr)^{\frac1n} $$
The second factor tends to $1$ as  $n\to\infty$, since
$$\ln\biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac23\Bigr)^n\biggr)^{\frac1n}=\frac1n\,\ln\biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac23\Bigr)^n\biggr)\sim_\infty \frac 1n\Bigl(\frac23\Bigr)^n $$
and both factors tend to $0$.

More generally you can prove this way:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^n+b^n)^{\frac1n}=\max(a,b).$$

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:*

$$3 = (3^n)^{1/n} < (2^n + 3^n)^{1/n} < (2\cdot 3^n)^{1/n} = 3 \cdot 2^{1/n}$$

Now squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

For an upper bound: $$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \leq \left(3^n+3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} = 3\sqrt[n]{2}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 3\sqrt[n]{2} = 3$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(2^n+3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \leq 3$$

For a lower bound:

$$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \geq \left(3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} = 3$$

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(2^n+3^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \geq 3$$

It's both less than or equal to $3$ and greater than or equal to $3$, so it must be equal to $3$.

Comment: I don't see how convergence follows. You showed boundedness but not monotonicity?

Comment: @dalastboss How's this?

Comment: Ah, with the edits it makes sense.

Comment: Isn't this @SimonS's answer?

Comment: @Did Yes, and I upvoted his. I had already typed out this answer so I figured it would not hurt to post it. Is that bad etiquette or something?

Comment: It is ridiculous to to think that these simple ideas would have any sort of ownership. Of course you can post it. Even entering in explaining the same idea in more or less detail, rephrasing it, is worth it at this level. Who knows in what small step a new student reading this might be struggling with.