# whats the lim$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ of this sequence to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

lim$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} $

I set  $y=$lim$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} $

ln$(y)=$  lim  $(1/n)$  ln$(2^n+3^n) $

and I get zero  multiplied with  infinity. 
How should i proceed? Tips are  welcomed as well

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129736/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, i am  taking down